# ASP.NET MVC Membership GetNumberOfUsersOnline returning incorrect value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, membership

I have the following line in a Controller

```
ViewData["UsersOnLineNow"] = Membership.GetNumberOfUsersOnline().ToString();
```

I am logged in as an Administrator but the above is returning a value of 0, verified by QickWatch. I was expecting a value of 1.

I also have the following in the Controller

```
ViewData["RegisteredUsers"] = Membership.GetAllUsers().Count.ToString();
```

This is returning the correct value of 2, myself included.

Anyone else had problems in this area?

Comment: Can you provide us with your membership configuration?

Comment: @hunter  I'm automatically logged in using a Remember Me function.

Comment: @frennky    I am using the standard AspNetSqlMembershipProvider generated by aspnet_regsql.exe

Comment: sure, but what does the code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN:

> GetNumberOfUsersOnline returns the
>   number of users for the current
>   ApplicationName where the
>   last-activity date is greater than the
>   current time less the
>   UserIsOnlineTimeWindow. The
>   last-activity date/time stamp is
>   updated to the current date and time
>   when user credentials are validated by
>   way of the ValidateUser or UpdateUser
>   method or when a call to a GetUser
>   overload that takes no parameters or
>   one that uses the userIsOnline
>   parameter to specify that the
>   date/time stamp should be updated.

Tip: You can try setting your UserIsOnlineTimeWindow to a higher value. Default value is 15 minutes, in the following example I've set it to 60.

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
  userIsOnlineTimeWindow="60">
  <providers>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
      type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
      connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
         enablePasswordReset="true" 
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
         requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
         minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: I think I have found the answer. If I use automatic login, then GetNumberOfUsersOnline() returns a value of 0 for my login. If I login every time, GetNumberOfUsersOnline() returns a value of 1.

Comment: You could've concluded that from my answer. When you log in, ValidateUser is called and last-activity gets updated. When you say 'remember me', the cookie is used so ValidateUser is never called.

Comment: I don't think I could have done. Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with the nuances of ASP.NET MVC etc yet. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: If you call the method GetUser(object providerUserKey, bool userIsOnline) then this will update the "LastActivityDate" and so will appear in the list of "online" users.